# Consulta con where en CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, codeigniter

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en la cual me me muestre un articulo en esecifico usando la biblioteca uri

En el index muestro una lista de cursos, si doy click a un curso por medio del id recuperado quiero mostrar solo ese curso de forma individual.

me muestra todas los cursos pero no me muestra el individual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver, el url si cambia con respecto al id recuperado de la consulta.
este es mi controlador

```
function index(){
        $data['segmento'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->view('codigoFacilito/headers');
        if(!$data['segmento']){
            $data['cursos'] = $this->codigofacilito_model->obtenerCursos();
        }
        else{
            $data['cursos'] = $this->codigofacilito_model->obtenerCurso($data['segmento']);
        }
        $this->load->view('cursos/cursos', $data);
    }
```

Este es mi modelo

```
function obtenerCurso($id){
        $this->db->where('idCurso', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('cursos');
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Esta es mi vista

```
<?php
    if($cursos){
        foreach ($cursos->result() as $curso) {
 ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?= $curso->idCurso ?>"><?= $curso->nombreCurso ?></a></li>
        </ul>
<?php
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<p>Error en la aplicación</p>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

saludos y gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Prueba tus rutas, porque quizás no le estés indicando que esa función en el controlador va a recibir parámetros a través de la url.

Ejemplo:

```
$route['miruta/(:any)'] = "controlador/funcion_controlador/$1";
```

Así te debe funcionar sin problemas, el resto parace que lo estás haciendo bien.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces referencia al método index (por defecto, nombre del controlador) con un parámetro de entrada para un determinado controlador, en tu caso quieres usar cursos, debes incluir también en la URL el método index detrás del nombre del controlador y luego el parámetro. Con tu URL está intentando acceder dentro del controlador cursos al método 1. Te explico a continuación:

Tu pones:

**localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/cursos/1** <-- Intenta buscar en el controlador cursos el método 1 y no existe, y te muestra esa página.

Deberías poner:

**localhost/Codeigniter/index.php/cursos/index/1** <-- He incluye un parámetro de entrada en el método index, por ejemplo. O accedes con el método $this->uri->segment(X) donde X es la posición del id en la URI.

Así se soluciona el problema ;)